# How to use SELECT inside COUNT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view, count

I have this view:

myVIEW: (id,percent)

I want to make another view, which will be like this:

LASTVIEW: (lastID, lastPR, counter)

and in "counter", in every line I want to have how money id`s have a bigger percent than the percent of this line. so I tried:

```
CREATE VIEW LASTVIEW(lastID, lastPR, counter) AS
SELECT id AS lastID, percent AS lastPR
COUNT (SELECT id FROM myVIEW WHERE percent < lastPR) AS counter,
FROM myVIEW;
```

Comment: Use your other query as a subquery in your `FROM`. Read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your are almost there. Try this:

```
SELECT id AS lastID, percent AS lastPR, (SELECT Count(id) 
FROM myVIEW bigger 
WHERE bigger.percent > myv.percent) AS counter
FROM myVIEW myv
```

Comment: it works! thanks!
but I have a strange Segmentation fault (core dumped)!

Comment: do you know why is the Segmentation  ?

Comment: I have no ideas how a database system get segmentation fault. Are you using your own program to run the query? If so, we need check your code.

Comment: ok I put it in the edit. it is not the same parameters as before because now I put the real code copy paste

Comment: Check the size of my_cmd. You now have a.much longer query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following select query for creating your view

```
SELECT lastID,lastPR,counter
FROM (SELECT A.id AS lastID,A.percent AS lastPR,count(B.id) AS counter
FROM myVIEW A,myVIEW B WHERE B.percent<A.percent
GROUP BY A.id,A.percent)
```